# Program keeps running when using elasticsearch scroll in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I tried running a simple search scroll of elasticsearch using Java High level API, and it is returning search results, but the program keeps running after retrieving all the data....

Why does it keep running and how to fix this?

```
public boolean ScrollUsers( UserSegmenter ref ) throws IOException {
        final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(10));
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("usertest");
        searchRequest.scroll(scroll);
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        //searchSourceBuilder.query(MatchQuery("title", "Elasticsearch"));
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search( searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT );
        String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
        SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

        while (searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0) {
            // I am printing fetched data here

            SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId);
            scrollRequest.scroll(scroll);
            searchResponse = client.scroll(scrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
            searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
        }
        ClearScrollRequest clearScrollRequest = new ClearScrollRequest();
        clearScrollRequest.addScrollId(scrollId);
        ClearScrollResponse clearScrollResponse = client.clearScroll(clearScrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        return clearScrollResponse.isSucceeded();
    }
```

My code has no other threads running... Its just this function for testing purpose.

EDIT: It's not the while loop. I tried removing it, same results

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println("hi");
        UserSegmenter obj = new UserSegmenter();
        obj.segmentUsers();
        System.out.println("finishing main");
    }
```

I get the message "finishing main" but still the program keeps running

Comment: maybe your while loop never ends, the scroll gets data continuously.

Comment: @Shafiul not the case, I tried removing it, same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.... I had to manually close the DB's connection... and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend using [try with resources](https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources), else the elastic search client would not be closed if an exception occurs.

```
try (ElasticSearchClient client = new ElasticSearchClient(config)) {

}


class ElasticSearchClient extends AutoClosable {

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        if (this.client != null) {
            this.client.close();
        }
    }
}
```